# Proguard: NoSuchMethodError: android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard, androidhttpclient

I get this of course when I obfuscate the build and run, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I tried adding all of these my proguard config file, but it didn't help:

```
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-keep interface android.net.http.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.** { *; }
-keep interface android.net.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient { *; }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by adding:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
```

Grr